# How to align numbers in parentheses

Tags: horizontal-alignment, parentheses

This code  aligns the 4 and the -3 roughly centered, i.e., the 4 is centered above the -3. I would like the 4 and the 3 to be perfectly vertically aligned, with the negative sign out to the left and the left parenthesis accommodating. How can I do this?

```
 \begin{align*}
    x = \begin{pmatrix}
            4 \\
           -3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
 \end{align*}
```

Comment: use `array` and a r-aligned column (note this is horizontal alignment rather than vertical alignment, vertical alignment refers to aligning to the top or the bottom of a box)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two ways: either use a `\phantom{-}` for the number without a `–` (to be used for each such number), or load `mathtools` and use its `pmatrix*` environment, which allows for an optional alignment specifier:

```
\begin{equation*}
    x = \begin{pmatrix*}[r] 
            4 \\
           -3 \\
        \end{pmatrix*}
        \qquad
    x = \begin{pmatrix}
        \phantom{-} 4 \\
           -3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
    4\\-3
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\[
x=\parenVectorstack[r]{4\\-3}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to align `4` and `-3` vertically at the right, would be to adopt a simple package called [`spalign`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spalign). Looking the screenshot you can see the result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[ \spalignvector[r]{4 -3} \]
\end{document}
```